# "Export to Spreadsheet" function to be embed into a button on a ASPX page using SharePoint 2007 designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer

May I ask how to create a button that function like the 'Export to Spreadsheet' (shown in the picture) on a ASPX file using SharePoint 2007 Designer?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below link should help you. You just need to build the appropriate URL for the excel export.

http://www.sharepointkings.com/2009/12/creating-export-to-excel-link-in.html

Comment: I notice that it will come as a file - iqy format and not xls or xlsx file format. Is it possible to make it come as a xls or xlsx file format?

Comment: The reason is because iqy file contain some sensitive information that I do not want the user to know it. (Unless there is a way to hide those information)

Comment: That is how the export function works. The calls that it makes actually query SharePoint so that when saved it can always refresh later should the SharePoint data change. It is possible to write code that does similar stuff, but it can get complex depending on what you want.